# How to push through transaction that has been pending for 2 weeks using Blockchain.info?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, blockchain.info

I'm using blockchain.info and was trying to send some bitcoin to Binance. It's been 2 weeks and it is still pending because I put too low of a fee. I'm wondering what method I can use to push this through and how to do it using blockchain.info Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would refer you to:
[Q: Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

But I'm going to make it simple for you.

You basically got two options:

**1. Wait it out.**
Easiest solution. Wait until the transaction gets picked up or dropped.

**2. Ask miners for help**
Some mining pools and miners offer services to allow you to prioritize your transaction in their mempool so that it is chosen sooner for inclusion in a block. One such service is https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/. Also you can [find others here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_accelerator).

Some [members on Bitcointalk.org offer free transaction accelerator services](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=52.0), some of them have access to several pools. If urgent, you may consider the paid services(Beware of the scammy ones though).

<s>**3. Rebroadcast**</s>
You can try to manually broadcast the transaction, but this probably won't help you at all because your fee is low.

<s>**4. Replace by Fee (RBF)**</s> 
Won't work with blockchain.info.

<s>**5. Child Pays for Parent (CPFP)**</s>
Won't work with Binance.